# Which control charts to use to track mortality

Tags: r, time-series, quality-control, mortality

I am trying to implement control charts in my organization (healthcare) to track various quality outcomes. The first one i want to do is mortality( # patient deaths/ month(or week) ). I have a data going back 15-20 years, the number of patients have been increasing steadily and so is the number of deaths. We have two main hospitals where we serve our patients. I have done some online reading and its kinda confusing on what would be the ideal way to go about it. Can someone share some documents/books which can guide me. Will a simple IMR control chart be useful in this case? I don't just wanna run random code and produce some charts unless i can derive some meaningful and correct insights from it.